# How to set class/instance variables that are read from plain file in python

Tags: python, oop

I have a configuration file named config.ini with following contents

```
env='test'
target_database='snowflake'
con_info = dict(username=usrname,
                password=pwd,
                account=account
                database=db
                ...
                ...
                )
seed_query = "some select query"
```

I want to read the config.ini file and create instance variables or class variables.

If I use the below snippet without class, then the variables are getting appended to globals() and hence I am able to access the variables once they are executed in the current session.

```
  with open(r'C:\Users\username\proj\config.ini') as f:
        print("Reading the configuration file:")
        exec(f.read())
```

I have written the above block in the constructor and a instance method, both did not help. I think the variables are lost because of local scope.

```
class File_Read:
    def read_config():
        with open(r'C:\Users\username\proj\config.ini') as f:
                print("Reading the configuration file:")
                exec(f.read())

fr = File_Read()
fr.read_config()
```

If I print(locals()['seed_query']) inside the definition, it displays the value. But once the function is exiting, the locals are lost.

Is there a way to create instance/class variables by reading the config file instead of manually doing below

```
def __init__(self):
    self.env=<env read from file>,
    self.target_database=<target_database read from file>
    self.conn_info = <conn_info read from file>
    ...
    ...
```

Can I put all these variables in __init__.py class and will that set these variables as global?

Comment: Using `exec` is to be avoided most of the time because it makes code hard to read and maintain and also can introduce security problems. Why do you want to write code in your config file? Why not just use a standard format, like JSON, YAML, etc., for which Python already has libraries (the standard library includes a JSON module, for example)?

Comment: I know this is not an answer to your question, but you might want to rethink what you are trying to do here. You are basically **executing** an configuration file, rather than reading from it. This is a security hazard waiting to happen. I would recommend to use the builtin module `configparser`. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)

Comment: @JarroVGIT,@ndc85430. Thanks for your reply. Acutally, I have created a class which transforms my data. All the logic is divided into multiple functions. These functions may require the parameters coming from file. So I wanted these to be created as instance/class variables of this class so that they can be accessible anywhere when the methods are called with the object.  

Based on your comments,can I write the code like below
1) initialize a variable holding configParser(cp) obj in the constructor
2) cp obj is now available to all instance methods. so required variables can be accessed.